# Cant get ResourceID Mono-Android

Tags: android, .net

I have a spinner that sets an image view resource based on the selected item from the list. The problem is when I go to retrieve the resource ID, I always get back a 0, or unknown member.

Spinner item selected()

```
    private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
        string toast = string.Format("{0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
        var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.stateView);
        var resourceId = 0;

        resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier(toast, "drawable", PackageName);
        imageView.SetImageResource(resourceId);
        Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

I have tried every combination of Resource.GetIdentifier(string, string, string), but I am not having any luck.

The resource is located in Resource.Designer.cs, and when debugging if I edit value of resource id to one of the ID of items in Resource.Designer.Drawable the function works as expected.

Does any one know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never worked with Mono-Android, & apologies if you tried this already, but... are you sure you're matching the right syntax for Resources.GetIdentifier ? have you also tried "drawable.png" (or whatever extension) instead of "drawable"?

**edit:

on regular Android, i believe the resources aren't inflated until the view is in place, the resourceID aren't valid until they are on the screen. in order to set an imageView's source, we use something static like ...

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash_screen);
```

where "splash_screen.png" is a file stored under res/drawable-small/

not sure if you've doubled checked your file name, and that it's in the right folder?